# How can one access the "Active View Viewable" metric via the AdSense API

Tags: adsense-api

While the "Active View Viewable" metric is available in the AdSense UI, it appears that it has never been exposed to the AdSense Management API. Is it indeed possible to access this metric (perhaps requiring intervention from the Google AdSense team)? If so how?

Comment: Looks like it wasn't possible in 2015 https://groups.google.com/d/msg/adsense-api/Z9tyCN2H3G8/VI-9KdSXBQAJ I doubt anything has changed since then